# Implement small blur effect over text

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to implement the small blur effect over my text when my delete banner goes up. The image shows what I am trying to do However I had no luck. I am using Tailwind but do not know if I am using the correct classes for it.

[image]

I am trying to use

```
                    <TrashIcon
                      className="h-6 w-6"
                      title="Delete Note"
                      titleId="deleteNote"
                    />
                  </button>

                )
              }
            </div>
            <div className={`text-gc-gray-900 mb-4 ${showDeleteBanner[index] ? 'bg-gradient-to-t from-white to-white' : ''}`}>{note.attributes.note}</div>
            {showDeleteBanner[index] && (
              <div className={`absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 h-auto overflow-hidden transition-transform duration-300 ease-in-out transform ${
                  showDeleteBanner[index]
                    ? "translate-y-0"
                    : "translate-y-full"
                } mt-3 bg-white`}>
                <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center py-3 px-4 bg-white">
                  <div>Are you sure you want to delete this note?</div>
                  <div className="flex items-center justify-center mt-3">
                    <button
                      className="flex items-center border px-8 py-2 mr-4 rounded-lg"
                      onClick={() => handleDeleteBanner(index)}
                    >
                      <XMarkIcon className="w-6 h-6 mr-3"/>
                      Cancel
                    </button>
                    <button
                      className="flex items-center border px-8 py-2 rounded-lg"
                    >
                      <TrashIcon className="w-6 h-6 mr-3" />
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>`
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [example].

Comment: Technically and visually that not a *"blur"*. That's just a gradient from white to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `bg-gradient-to-b from-black from-70% bg-clip-text text-[transparent]`.

`-webkit-mask-image` and `::before` might be another solution.

Here is a [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/oyPfb3G2tX).